# C++ // Not all control paths return a value

Tags: c++

```
int bounce(int n) {
    if (n == 0)
    {
        cout << "0" << endl;
    }
    if (n > 0)
    {
        cout << n << endl;
        bounce(n - 1);
        cout << n << endl;
    }
}

int main() 
{
    int x;
    cout << "Choose a number: ";
    cin >> x;
    cout << bounce(x) << endl;
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

I recently started for my first time with C++ (2 hours ago or so :D ) and the problem i have is "Bounce: not all control paths return a value", I don't know how to fix this, obviously i need return 0; or something somewhere in the function but i can't find out where without ruining how it works.
Example : bounce(5) ==> prints out 5 4 3 2 1 0 1 2 3 4 5
TL DR: Where to place the return in bounce to make it work correctly.

Comment: Consider the case of n<0

Comment: Where do you return a value?

Comment: ^ ... and `void` return type.

Comment: @Chuu Consider every case.

Comment: Printing text to stdout and returning a value are not the same thing.

Comment: The message isn't quite accurate. Not ANY control paths return a value!

Comment: I never return a value but it still works kind of , i just want it to print out for example bounce(3) ==> 3 2 1 0 1 2 3

Comment: As i wrote above, i just started with C++, i have no idea what im doing so far so yeah :) Trying on Recursion functions

Comment: If you don't want to return something change the return value from `int` to `void`

Comment: Don't return anything; change your declaration from `int bounce(int n)` to `void bounce(int n)`. `void` means you are not returning anything, which is what you want.

Comment: Ugh, then i get : binary '<<': no operator found which takes a right-hand operand of type 'void' (or there is no acceptable conversion)

Comment: Then you want the function to return something. Just do it!

Comment: Don't call `bounce` in your `cout` statement then. Just call `bounce` alone, without the surrounding `cout`

Comment: Solved it, changed "cout << bounce(x) << endl;" to "bounce(x);"

Comment: Yes, you want to replace `cout << bounce(x) << endl;` with `bounce(x);`. The `bounce` function itself is what is doing the output, you don't need to output anything else.

Comment: Yeah saw that now, thank you all very much :) I will prolly come up with more noob-questions :D

Comment: I hope not, always do some research first.

Comment: @Widdin _"I will prolly come up with more noob-questions :D"_ No please! I beg you should read [all of these articles](http://stackoverflow.com/help/asking) before asking your next question here.

Comment: It's not that easy to find a specific exactly the same problem :)

Comment: If i name this file bounce.cpp then how do i call the function from a header.h file? Like if i made a menu in the header?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Actually none of your control paths returns a value. As you only use the function to print something on the screen, it does not have to return anything. Just make the return type void:

```
void bounce(int n) {
    /*...*/
}
```

And then dont `cout` the result of the function call (once you make it `void` the function wont return anything anyhow), i.e. instead of:

```
std::cout << bounce(x) << std::endl;
```

simply write

```
bounce(x);
```

You already print on the screen inside the function.

Answer (score 2):

When you define a function in C++, you specify the return type before the function name.

Your `int bounce()` function is declared as returning an integer but it does not return any values at all. Therefore, that causes an error.

You can declare your function using `void bounce()`, which tells the compiler that your function will not return any values. That will eliminate the error.

*Note: Although you use `cout` to display your values, this is different from returning a value in the way we are talking about. Returns values are specified using the `return` keyword.*